# Xcode: compile .c file in ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

For a library that I am including in my iOS project (SSZipArchive), it is required that I use compile flags to compile the files individually in ARC.

This obviously needs to be done for the .m files within the library, but what about .c files? Are they even affected by ARC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.c` file is plain C, it should contain no Objective-C and therefore nothing affected by ARC which applies to Objective-C(++) code.